# ebproof and Gentzen-style proofs: How to locally change horisontal separation of branches?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, ebproof

Package [`ebproof`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ebproof?lang=en) is a way to write [Gentzen-style formal proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus) in LaTeX. For example, the following is done with `ebproof`:

[image: Gentzen tree example]

Of course, the blue contour is added later.

***Q:*** How to move/shift the branch circled in blue to the left as shown? The horisontal spacing between the two main branches is too long. I would like to change *only this one* horisontal spacing. Using the option 'separation=1em' changes spacing globally which is not an option in this case (would lead to overlap in the upper half of the right-hand branch).

- It should be a "rigid transformation", i.e. other sizes, lenghts and angles should be preserved.
- When the right-hand branch is moved to the left, the inference line underneath should "scale" (shorten) accordingly.
- Ideally, the solution would still work when the code is wrapped inside `sidewaysfigure` as is shown in MWE below (uncomment appropriate lines and packages).

---

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ebproof} %for Gentzen-style proofs
\ebproofset{right label template=\scriptsize\inserttext}
%\usepackage{rotating} %for sidewaysfigure
%\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\begin{document}

    %\begin{sidewaysfigure}
    \footnotesize
            \[ \begin{prooftree}[separation=1em]
            \hypo {A} %left-hand branch leaf
            \infer1[\tiny \text{(rule)}]{A} %left-hand branch node
            \hypo {ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTUVWXYZ} %right-hand branch leaf
            \infer1[\tiny \text{(rule)}]{ABCDEFGHIJKL} %right-hand branch node
            \hypo {0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTUVWXYZ} %right-hand branch leaf
            \infer2[\tiny \text{(rule)}]{ABCDEFGHIJKL} %right-hand branch node
            \infer1[\tiny \text{(rule)}]{A} %right-hand branch node
            \infer1[\tiny \text{(rule)}]{A} %right-hand branch node
            \infer1[\tiny \text{(rule)}]{A} %right-hand branch node
            \infer2[\tiny \text{(rule)}]{ABC} %root
            \end{prooftree} \]
    %\end{sidewaysfigure}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can locally change the `separation` option by inserting it as option to the relevant `\infer` macro, before the number denoting the arity, such as `\infer[separation=1em]1{X}`. This works regardless of rotation and placement. In you case, in order to shift the right tree over the left one, you can use a negative value for `separation`.

You may want to set `right label template=\tiny\inserttext` instead of overriding the font size locally everywhere. Also, if you want to center the diagram, maybe better use `\centering` and not some math-mode construction which is not needed here.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating} %for sidewaysfigure
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ebproof} %for Gentzen-style proofs
\ebproofset{right label template=\tiny\inserttext}

\begin{document}

    \begin{sidewaysfigure}
    \footnotesize\centering
        \begin{prooftree}[separation=1em]
            \hypo {A} %left-hand branch leaf
            \infer1[\text{(rule)}]{A} %left-hand branch node
            \hypo {ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTUVWXYZ} %right-hand branch leaf
            \infer1[\text{(rule)}]{ABCDEFGHIJKL} %right-hand branch node
            \hypo {0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTUVWXYZ} %right-hand branch leaf
            \infer2[\text{(rule)}]{ABCDEFGHIJKL} %right-hand branch node
            \infer1[\text{(rule)}]{A} %right-hand branch node
            \infer1[\text{(rule)}]{A} %right-hand branch node
            \infer1[\text{(rule)}]{A} %right-hand branch node
            \infer[separation=-4em]2[\text{(rule)}]{ABC} %root
        \end{prooftree}
    \end{sidewaysfigure}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, yes! Thank you very much. The solution is a lot simpler than I had hoped. Your other comments about formatting ("tiny", "centering") are also well taken.